# Overriding a property for XML deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I'm using an API to search for hotels, we will call this type 1. It gets deserialized by `XmlSerializer` into my `Hotel` class and this all works fine as expected. My issue is when I'm making another API call, which we will call type 2, and want to re-use my `Hotel` class.

The API calls are pretty similar, type 1 returns a list of hotels nearby and type 2 returns further details for a particular hotel. One of the extra pieces of information I'm trying to parse is images. In type 1 and in my `Hotel` class I have:

```
[XmlElement("images")]
public virtual string ImageURL { get; set; }
```

which works fine for the type 1 call. Now for the type 2 call it is an array of images rather than just the one string. I've created a new class called `Hotel2` which derives from `Hotel` and looks like this:

```
public class Hotel2 : Hotel
{
    [XmlArray("images")]
    [XmlArrayItem("url")]
    public List<string> ImageURLs { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public override string ImageURL
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.ImageURLs != null && this.ImageURLs.Count > 0 ? this.ImageURLs[0] : String.Empty);
        }
    }
```

}

and you can see I have a new property `ImageURLs` (note the 's') which handles the array. I'm also overriding the `ImageURL` property which returns the first Image in the `ImageURLs` collection and marking it as `XmlIgnore` so it doesn't get deserialized.

The issue is that it seems `XmlSerializer` ignores my `XmlIgnore` property and attempts to deserialize the base property thus resulting in this exception: `The XML element 'images' from namespace '' is already present in the current scope. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element.`

Any idea what I can do here? I've also tried to hide the property with `new` to no success.

Comment: Personally, I would say that having `<images>some single thing</images` and `<images><url>someting</url>...<url>something else</url></images>` is a really bad idea from a schema viewpoint. If the first one was `<image>something</image>` (note no `s`), it is trivial to do, and much clearer.

Comment: @MarcGravell, I agree but the API is out of my control unfortunately and the reasoning is due to "legacy issues".

Comment: you can do it with `XmlAttributeOverrides`, but frankly my advice here would be: go for two models

Comment: Yeah, I was actually thinking of editing the XML manually, e.g. replacing `<images>` with `<image>` for API type 1, as you suggest but  that seems dirty and was wondering if there was a better way. I'll take a look into `XmlAttributeOverrides` as I don't fancy using two models (two many repeat properties).

Comment: note you **MUST** cache and re-use the serializer instance when using `XmlAttributeOverrides`; it **WILL** leak memory if you `new` it each time.

Answer (score 0):

After Marc suggested using `XmlAttributeOverrides`, it felt a little 'dirty' so I decided to create an abstract `HotelBase` class, making the `ImageURL` property abstract and decorating it with `XmlIgnore`. Now I can override it in my `Hotel1` and `Hotel2` classes.